# SQL ORDER BY - how to honour same order as list in WHEN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

A very basic SQL question I am forgetting.

Given

```
select * from customers
where customer_id in ('29383', '49405', '47483', '10209','46383', '93838');
```

...how can I order the results, such that it orders them in the same order as the `in('...` clause?

for example, rather than `order by customer_id desc;` I want the results to be:

```
29383
49405
47483
10209
46383
93838
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On SQL Server, you may order using a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM customers
WHERE customer_id in ('29383', '49405', '47483', '10209','46383', '93838')
ORDER BY CASE customer_id
         WHEN '29383' THEN 1
         WHEN '49405' THEN 2
         WHEN '47483' THEN 3
         WHEN '10209' THEN 4
         WHEN '46383' THEN 5
         WHEN '93838' THEN 6 END;
```

Note that if you have a persistent need for this ordering, it might make more sense to keep this `customer_id` values and their mappings/orderings in a separate table.  Then, join to this table and use the ordering value in your `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: thank you - I should have mentioned this is SQL Server and I get an error:  'field' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @Steerpike Yes, you should have mentioned that.  I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `IN` you could consider joining on a [table value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) containing the distinct list of `customer_id` and sort order.

```
select c.* 
from customers c
join (values(1, '29383'),
            (2, '49405'),
            (3, '47483'),
            (4, '10209'),
            (5, '46383'),
            (6, '93838')) v(pos, customer_id) on v.customer_id = c.customer_id
order by v.pos
```

Or you could use `OPENJSON` in a similar way

```
SELECT c.*
FROM   customers c
       JOIN OPENJSON('["29383", "49405", "47483", "10209","46383", "93838"]') j
         ON j.[value] = c.customer_id
ORDER  BY CAST(j.[key] AS INT)
```